# Windows 2k8 R2 - What is the UserDN belongs to 1 OU that inside the other OU?

Tags: windows-server-2008, command-line-interface

I would like to know what is the UserDN (User Distinquished Name) for a user belongs to 1 OU, but that OU also belongs to the other OU.

UserDN for the first OU: "CN=George Luong,OU=People,DC=quang,DC=com"

Look at the picture to see what I want to know!

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`CN=Joe Blow,OU=Office1,OU=People,DC=quang,DC=com`

The CN is the common name of the user. Then from left to right, list every component in the path from where the object is all the way up the tree until you come up with a fully qualified path that leads all the way up to the root of the domain. That's the distinguished name.

Here's some more reading from Microsoft on distinguished names:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366101(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: If you look at the "Object" tab in ADUC (enable Advanced view) you can see the path but in reverse.